# Records may disappear after some time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a code who create a new database in this location:

> /Users/williamlima/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/3989C1D3-A1C1-4DDA-892F-29C9A23A180F/Documents/fazerbem.sql

I managed to insert some records in the database that was created. However not used the application on Xcode for 4 days, when I returned to my project, the appstore updated Xcode, but when I start the program again, the records were no longer there, but the database was.

What could have caused this kind of thing? that was upgrading from Xcode, or database stores records for a certain time and then erase them?,

Comment: I don't think the update has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have long-lasting data, you could try and switch the file type from sql to .plist (though I'm not sure if that would conflict with your code or not).

Which would look a bit like this:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    return [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourappname.plist"];
}
```

If not, you may want to check your archiver and unarchiver coding methods. It could be that you're not correctly **encoding/decoding the data**. I can edit this if you need me to show an example.